# CSS style for text starting with "> "

Tags: css

I am creating a [userstyle for mailman/pipermail archives](https://userstyles.org/styles/119453/gnu-mailman-pipermail-mailing-lists) for the [Stylish Addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/stylish/) for Firefox and Chrome.

Now the only thing left would be to give the quotes a unique style so I would have to address only text that is preceeded by `>` and create a CSS for that.

How can I address those text parts with CSS only?

Comment: sounds like you need javascript, as far as I know there is no way to target elements based on their content. I don't suppose the `>` character is wrapped in it's own DOM element?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS selector for elements containing certain text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Looks like they were thinking about such a selector for the CSS3 spec
>   but it didn't make the cut.
>
> `:contains()` CSS3 selector:
>   https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#content-selectors

Answer (score 2):

You cannot target element based on their content. You can check the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors).

You can try to use Jquery or Javascript which have functions like `td:contains` to achieve that.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can't using CSS only. As stated from w3schools:

> In CSS, selectors are patterns used **to select the element(s)** you want
>   to style.

`Elements` being `tags`. As long as the part you want to style isn't wrapped inside a `span` for example, you can't style it.